# How can I make a outer join in a complex Rails has_many scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, scope, psql

My goal is to make a scope where I can see all the completed courses of a `Member` object.

A `Course` is composed of many `Sections`. There is one `Quiz` per `Section`. And every single `Quiz` must be set to `complete` in order for the `Course` to be complete.

For example :

```
Course
   Section A -> Quiz A ( Complete )
   Section B -> Quiz B ( Complete )
   Section C -> Quiz C ( Complete )
```

This is my best attempt at writing this kind of scope :

```
# Member.rb

has_many :completed_courses, -> {
  joins(:quizzes, :sections)
  .where(quizzes: {completed: true})
  .group('members.id HAVING count(sections.quizzes.id) = count(sections.id)')
}, through: :course_members, source: :course
```

The part that I'm missing is this part `count(sections.quizzes.id)` which isn't actually SQL. I'm not entirely sure what kind of `JOIN` this would be called, but I need some way to `count` the completed quizzes that belong to the course and compare that number to how many sections. If they are equal, that means all the quizzes have been completed.

To be fair, just knowing the name of this kind of JOIN would probably set me in the right direction.

---

**Update**

I tried using @jamesdevar 's response :

```
has_many :completed_courses, -> {
  joins(:sections)
  .joins('LEFT JOIN quizzes ON quizzes.section_id = sections.id')
  .having('COUNT(sections.id) = SUM(CASE WHEN quizzes.completed = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)')
  .group('courses.id')
}, through: :course_members, source: :course
```

But it returns a `[ ]` value when it shouldn't. For example I have this data :

```
->  Course{id: 1}
    -> Section{id: 1, course_id: 1}
        -> Quiz{section_id: 1, member_id: 1, completed: true}
```

The Course has one Section in total. The Section may have hundreds of Quizzes associated with it from other Members, but for this specific Member, his Quiz is completed.

I think it has something to do with this SQL comparison not being unique to the individual member.

```
.having('COUNT(sections.id) = SUM(CASE WHEN quizzes.completed = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)')
```

The actual SQL produced is this :

```
 SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" 
 INNER JOIN "sections" ON "sections"."course_id" = "courses"."id" 
 INNER JOIN "course_members" ON "courses"."id" = "course_members"."course_id" 
 LEFT JOIN quizzes ON quizzes.section_id = sections.id 
 WHERE "course_members"."member_id" = $1 
 GROUP BY courses.id 
 HAVING COUNT(sections.id) = SUM(CASE WHEN quizzes.completed = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
 ORDER BY "courses"."title" 
 ASC  [["member_id", 1121230]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
has_many :completed_courses, -> {
  joins(:sections)
  .joins('LEFT JOIN quizzes ON quizzes.section_id = sections.id')
  .having('COUNT(sections.id) = SUM(CASE WHEN quizzes.completed = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)')
  .group('courses.id')
}, through: :course_members, source: :course
```

In this case `having` will filter each `cources.id` group by condition when each section has completed quizz.

Comment: This is really incredible, thank you. It doesn't exactly work though as it always returns a `[ ]` value even if all quizzes were completed. I'll update above with an example.

Comment: Woops, just figured it all out ( which had to do with other attributes not aligning that I hadn't told you about ). Thank you so much for your help! You totally helped me solve this. Thanks so much!